# Develop flex Mobile Application using flash builder and Run/debug it On android virtual Emulator

Tags: android, flash-builder, android-virtual-device, flex-mobile

I want to connect/integrate my flex mobile project with android virtual device from avd manager. So when i run or debug my flex mobile project, it should run/debug on the virtual device rather then as a mobile application. Please note that i don't want to connect an android device physicaly, which is done by connecting it via usb. I simply need to run/debug it on a android virtual device that will be running already.

Comment: too few flex developers nowadays.. hope we have someone who can answer this..